# Memory Allocation Error

Tags: r, memory

I came across a memory allocation error while running R. The error says:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 374.2 Mb
```

I also tried using this line of code:

```
memory.limit()
memory.limit(size=2200)
```

Is there something missing here? There is still an error when I try to plot it. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Something else in your workspace is, also, consuming memory and R informs that the 374.2 Mb requested by object -say- "x" somewhere are not available; i.e. memory used + memory of 'x' > available memory

Comment: You should include a list of packages, variables, data frames (with size) and manipulations you are trying to complete. Any given entity can exist in as much as three places in memory when apply functions to it. We can better help you if you tell us more about the system and the r set up